# Python FuncAnimation not recognizing update

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm learning how to animate in python for one of my projects and I'm basing my code off of the following example from [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/drawing-animated-gifs-with-matplotlib).

My adaption of their code goes as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py, os, glob, sys, time
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def update(i):
    for j in np.arange(0,10):
        for k in np.arange(0,10):
            for channel in ["N","E"]:
                x = some_x_value
                y = some_y_value
                line = plt.loglog(x,y)
                ax.set_xlabel(label)
    return line, ax


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.arange(0,10), interval=200)
    anim.save('Test.gif', dpi=80, writer='imagemagick')
```

And when I try to run my script I get the following error:
Name Error: name 'update' is not defined.

As I said before, I'm still learning how to animate and don't understand all of what's going on in the code tutorial I found. However, I'm very confused as to why update isn't recognized at all as the way I call update seems to be exactly the same as what's in the tutorial.

Comment: There are a bunch of other undefined names in there (like `ssPlot`).

Comment: @tcaswell I didn't post all of my defined functions because I didn't want to clutter my question, but stuff like ssPlot is already defined elsewhere for me and has previously worked fine. It's only update right now that is returning the Name Error.

Comment: Can you reduce your example to code that demonstrates the problem you are asking about?

Comment: and can be copy-paste-run by other developers.

Comment: @tcaswell I condensed my code. Python doesn't want to recognize update when it's being called in FuncAnimation even though I have it defined as seen in the above (simplified) code.

Comment: The code in this question still does not run (name errors on `some_x_value`, `some_y_value` and `label`).

Comment: Found and fixed my issue. I had def update(i) contained inside my class() with the other def someFunctions(self, ...) when it should have been defined outside of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def update(i, ln):
    i = i+1
    x = i
    y = i ** 2
    x_data = ln.get_xdata()
    y_data = ln.get_ydata()
    ln.set_data(np.concatenate(([x], x_data)),
                np.concatenate(([y], y_data)))
    return ln


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xlim(1, 10)
    ax.set_ylim(1, 100)
    line, = ax.loglog([1], [1])
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.arange(0, 10), interval=200,
                         fargs=(line, ))
    anim.save('Test.gif', dpi=80, writer='imagemagick')
```

Works as expected.  This makes me think that there is some other error in your code which is getting masked.

Comment: I successfully recreated the tutorial example but am still having trouble getting my actual code to animate. I'll go back through my code and try to reverse engineer it, step-by-step. Thanks for looking into my issue though.